# Percentage float doesnt get get saved in number format in excel

Tags: python, pandas

I have converted a float column in a pandas dataframe to show percentage using:

```py
df[fieldname].apply(lambda x: "{0:.2f}%".format(x*100))
```

but when i save the file in excel using `df.to_excel()` it shows me that column in general format instead of number format in MS Excel.

Is there any way to save the data such that its in number format in excel?

Answer (score 0):

From the Pandas documentation for [`pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`](http://float_format%20:%20str,%20optional%20%20%20%20%20%20Format%20string%20for%20floating%20point%20numbers.%20For%20example%20float_format=%22%25.2f%22%20will%20format%200.1234%20to%200.12.):

```
Parameters:
    float_format : str, optional

    Format string for floating point numbers. For example float_format="%.2f" will format 0.1234 to 0.12.
```

Therefore, save the file to excel using: `df.to_excel(float_format="%.2f")`