# percentage formatting not shown in the excel file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I wanted to copy a specific part of a excel wb and save it into a wb
when i saved the df in a new wb the the  round formatting was correct, but the percentage formating was not shown in the new wb

```
df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='Vorlage Quellung',skiprows=6)


mein_df = df.loc[:9,['Dichte','Quellwert','Wasseraufnahme']]

# format
mein_df_format1 = mein_df.round({'Dichte':1,})

df_fertig = mein_df_format1.style.format({

    'Quellwert': '{:,.2%}'.format,
    'Wasseraufnahme': '{:,.1%}'.format
})

df_fertig.to_excel(r'C:\Users\uberfeld\Desktop\Auswertung\Langzeittess25.08.2019-Chep-95-95.xlsx')
```

Comment: Does the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58101930/percentage-float-doesnt-get-get-saved-in-number-format-in-excel?rq=1 help you? Setting 
 the `float_format` parameter in the to_excel function like `df.to_excel(float_format="%.2f")`?

Comment: not really, it didnt do much for me